# how to convert curl command line to pycurl code

Tags: python, curl, urllib2, pycurl

Here is my Original code

```
import urllib, urllib2
from xml.dom import minidom

base_url = 'test.com:8000'
username = 'MyId'
password = 'passwd'
search_query = 'search error | head 10'

# Login and get the session key
request = urllib2.Request(base_url + '/servicesNS/MyId/search/auth/login', 
data = urllib.urlencode({'username': username, 'password': password}))

server_content = urllib2.urlopen(request)

session_key = minidom.parseString(server_content.read()).\
getElementsByTagName('sessionKey')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
print "Session Key: %s" % session_key 

# Perform a search
request = urllib2.Request(base_url + '/servicesNS/MyId/search/search/jobs/export', 
data = urllib.urlencode({'search': search_query,'output_mode': 'json'}),
headers = { 'Authorization': ('Splunk %s' %session_key)})
search_results = urllib2.urlopen(request)
print search_results.read()
```

It causes an 404 error so I decided to use Curl.

I have this curl commend

```
  curl -k -u myID:Passwd -d 'search="google.com | head 10"' -d "output_mode=json" https://test.com:8089/servicesNS/myId/search/search/jobs/export
```

I am trying to use pycurl to call Joson.

How do I convert it to pycurl?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show us your code - what have you tried that doesn't work?

Comment: Why doesn't your `base_url` start with `'http://'`? And which of the two requests 404s?

Comment: your urllib2 code and the curl command do not match: different ports, different requests. ElementTree provides nicer xml api: [`session_key = etree.parse(server_content).findtext(".//sessionKey")`](http://ideone.com/gGyky4)

Comment: Have you read the pycurl tutorial, examples, and related docs on the [home page](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net)? If so, what part are you stuck on? If not… go read it and come back when you can answer the previous question.

Answer (score 7):

The best way to convert a curl command line to anything that uses [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) (like [pycurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/) or other bindings), is to run the command line with "[--libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--libcurl) output.c" appended to it, and then you check out that created embryo as it then shows what curl had to do.

Converting that C code to pycurl code is usually trivial.